# Chrome not picking up @font-face OTF

Tags: css

[My site here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html) won't pick up 'proxima nova' otf in Chrome and can't understand why.. Here's the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Proxima Nova';
    src: url("/Fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf") format('opentype');
}
```

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 20):

Just encountered the same problem, you don't need to specify format for otf fonts, just remove the last part of the `src` attribute:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Proxima Nova';
    src: url("/Fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf");
}
```

This comment helped me to sort this problem out:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2609#issuecomment-311231425

Comment: this should be the right reply for this question, it worked for me

Comment: to add additional context- in Chrome, the browser was not even trying download the font, not even a 404. I think that's what OP means by 'won't pick up', but clarifying in case its helpful to somebody else

Answer (score 3):

different browsers like different font file formats, for example IE will only acknowledge .eot and i think im right in saying that webkit browsers prefer .ttf files.

Use [Squirrel's font face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to create all the various font files you need, it will also give you an example of how to include them all properly in your css font face declarations

Comment: The WOFF format is preferable on WebKit browsers, but the @font-face generator will handle this.

Comment: I'm not sure, the quality has never decreased when Ive used it, try another one see if its any different http://fontface.codeandmore.com/

Answer (score 3):

If you see 404 error for this font request in browser console, the problem is not in the browser but rather on the server side. The solution is to add mime type for .otf file extension in IIS on the web server. Since otf is a pretty new format, it's not available in the default list of mime types in IIS serevr; you have to explicitly add one.

Answer (score 2):

Best for chrome is base64

src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

co generate this