# Angular - I imported a custom font but the same Roboto font is the one that is displayed

Tags: css, angular, fonts

I imported a font, but its not working. I did all the steps, i import evertything but when i place it on the css, it doesnt work.

I imported the font file to: src/assets/fonts/Beaufort W01 Regular.otf

then i added on the src/styles.css file this :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: beaufort;
  src: url("src/assets/fonts/Beaufort W01 Regular.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

then on the css component file this:

```
body{
  background-color: #048ea0;
  margin-top: 62px;
  font-family: beaufort,'arial', sans-serif;
}
```

But the font stays the same default one, the  Roboto one.

What i am missing?

Comment: Your path is wrong. Should just be `"/assets/fonts/Beaufort W01 Regular.otf"`

Comment: that dont solve the problem

Comment: Okay, besides that. Maybe this too,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400212/chrome-not-picking-up-font-face-otf

Comment: I just tried it exactly how you have it above with the correct path and it works. 
No need to remove format.

Answer (score 0):

i think your path is wrong, add this
 `@font-face {font-family: beaufort;src: url("assets/fonts/Beaufort W01 Regular.otf") format("opentype");}`